# How to generate all triangulations of an orientable surface?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gt.geometric-topology, surfaces

$\newcommand{\comb}{\mathrm{comb}}$Consider an orientable surface $S$ with punctures and boundaries (each boundary having at least a marked point).

A triangulation, up to orientation preserving homeomorphisms, of $S$ is described by a collection $T_{\comb}$ of triangles $t$ which themselves are cyclically ordered triples of labels associated to each edge, $t=(e_1,e_2,e_3)$. Let me call these data a *combinatorial triangulation*.

A combinatorial triangulation $T_{\comb}$ does not label unically a triangulation up to homeomorphism, because one can further permute the edge labels $e_i \to e_{\sigma(i)}$.

What are efficient ways to generate all combinatorial triangulations $T_{\comb}$ up to permutation of the edges? In other words, how to generate one combinatorial triangulation for each triangulation of the surface up to homeomorphism?

One way which I know is to use the Whitehead theorem, which says that any two triangulations are related by a sequence of flips (remove one edge from the triangulation and replace it with the other diagonal in the square thus formed). Then one can start from a triangulation, and sequentially flip all edges and then repeat with the triangulations thus obtained. Are there better options?

Clarification:
The triangulations I consider are such that the edges are at the marked points/punctures. For instance for a disk with 4 marked points on the boundaries we have two triangulations:
Let a=(12), b=(23),c=(34),d=(41),e=(13),f=(24), then the two triangulations are ((a,b,e),(c,d,e)) and ((d,a,f),(b,c,f)).

Comment: Clarifying questions: Is there a particular purpose to the punctures and boundaries in this question? Are you asking for an algorithm that produces a list of unlabelled combinatorial triangulations on, say, $n$ vertices or do you wish to count them?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have clarified this point in the question. I would like to create explicitly all triangulations, although even a counting function would be very interesting for me

Comment: From the formulation of your question it sounds like you are interested in generating all triangulations of a *given* (orientable surface with marked boundary) $S$, but would you also be interested in generating all triangulations of *all* orientable surfaces?  Because the latter problem is in some ways easier.  See Samuel Vidal's [An Optimal Algorithm to Generate Rooted Trivalent Diagrams and Rooted Triangular Maps](http://samuel.math.online.fr/articles/diaggen.pdf?origin%3Dpublication_detail) for one approach. (The problem also has some connections to lambda calculus...)

Answer (score 10):

Thom Sulanke has a program and a paper about this. Check out https://tsulanke.pages.iu.edu/graphs/surftri/ .

Incidentally, Sulanke's method does not require the triangulations to be stored, so memory is not a limitation. An implementation for the planar case is [plantri](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/plantri/) which we have used to make more than $10^{13}$ triangulations .

Answer (score 9):

Regarding enumeration: counting triangulations of surfaces with boundaries of prescribed lengts (number of vertices on each) is one with a long history. In the genus-0 case it dates back to Tutte in the sixties: Tutte, W. (1962). A Census of Planar Triangulations. Canadian Journal of Mathematics, 14, 21-38. See also Krikun, Maxim. Explicit enumeration of triangulations with multiple boundaries. Electron. J. Combin. 14 (2007), 61.

For the higher-genus case you could have a look at Goulden, I. P.; Jackson, D. M. The KP hierarchy, branched covers, and triangulations. Adv. Math. 219 (2008), no. 3, 932--951. Or the more physicist-oriented book by B. Eynard, Counting Surfaces, CRM Aisenstadt Chair lectures. But there are many more works out there.

Answer (score 7):

Jus as you describe it, breadth first search in the flip graph will generate all combinatorial triangulations (up to relabelling) in time only a small multiple of the size of the output.

Of course, the size of the output is super-exponential in the (unary) size of the topological data, so this is not as nice as it sounds.  (The upper bound comes a labelling argument: see Ben Burton's "isomorphism signatures".  The lower bound comes by importing a similar lower bound from counting cubic graphs.)

I do not know of a quick way to count the number of triangulations.  I agree that such a thing would be very interesting!

Comment: Could you please add some reference to these isomorphism signatures? 
Is there a version of this invariant working also for surfaces with marked points on the boundaries?

Comment: in fact I think it may be incredibly trivial to do it. One just has to produce a canonical labelling, which is easily done for a bordered surface (which means that the boundary segments are already labelled). One simply label the triangles (and using the orientation, the inner edges) of those triangles with at least one boundary edge exploiting the external labelling. Then removes these and continue by treating the former inner edges as new boundary edges

Comment: I learnt about isomorphism signatures from Regina, a program written by Ben Burton.  His focus is on three-dimensional triangulations, but the code also works "out of the box" in dimensions two up to eight.  Yes, it allows manifolds with boundary, but no, it does not incorporate marked points.  Here is a reference: Benjamin A. Burton. The Pachner graph and the simplification of 3-sphere triangulations.

Comment: The problem with this method is that you have to compare each triangulation with what you have found already to see if it is new.  It limits you to what you can store at once.  The method mentioned in my answer does not have this problem, so huge numbers of triangulations can be generated.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay: Interesting!  If I may, I have two questions. Q1: I see that "my way" takes vastly more memory.  But if I things understand correctly, "your way" takes more time.  How much more? Q2: While generating all triangulations using your method, is there any information we can save/record to accelerate generating them a second time?

Comment: @SamNead I haven't run Sulanke's program for years (let us know if you do) but plantri makes planar triangulations at several million per second. The time per triangulation actually decreases with size in the practical range of sizes. So I don't know why you think it is slower. I think it is probably much faster.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay - A single step of the "Whitehead algorithm" involves doing a single flip, computing a hash, and then checking to see if it is in the table (and inserting it if it is not there).  This is very fast.  I don't have a clear sense of the steps involved in the "isomorph-free"  algorithm.  I suppose that there is an expansion or contraction step, and then we check that some encoding is lexicographically early enough?  Could you please suggest a (very!) elementary reference?  (Or just sketch the technique?) Thank you!

Comment: @SamNead 
G. Brinkmann and B. D. McKay, Fast generation of planar graphs, MATCH Commun. Math. Comput. Chem., 58 (2007) 323-357.  See page 5 in this extended version:
https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/plantri-full.pdf

Comment: Both methods involve generating graphs then deciding whether to keep them.  So the main issues regarding efficiency are (1) how many graphs are constructed compared to how many are kept? (2) how quickly can the accept/reject test be done?  For the flipping method, an isomorphism class can be made by flipping any graph that is one flip away, and eventually will be (the cost of BFS is O(number of edges) which is the total flips over all isom classes). For the isomorph free method, the number of times each isomorphism class is constructed is usually much less (depends on the family). (continued)

Comment: (continued) For the flipping method, full isomorphism signatures are needed for each generated graph; linear time but still the major cost. For the isomorph free method, many (for some families, most) times the accept/reject decision can be made with only some cheap invariant and a full signature is only needed occasionally.  Only comparison of equally good implementations can made these comments quantitative.